# Can 'gaps' in autoincrementing ids / primary keys cause any problems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am concerned about some bugs that caused a primary key to have 'gaps' (they attempted to create records, but when they failed, the record wasn't created, and the next successfully created record skipped the id used for the failed record). The `users` table's id column now looks like so: 1, 2, 4, 5, 7 etc..

I feel like this may be a question where a junior developer will be very concerned about this, but a senior develop may know enough about how AR and the db interact, and how they work, such they they know there is absolutely nothing wrong with this.

So the question: can these 'gaps' in the id column (e.g. primary key) cause *any* problems?

I feel like it's a big deal - "the data has gaps in it" sounds really bad. But if everything works, and this is actually perfectly okay, then there's obviously no need to worry. But I am unsure.

#### Notes

- I assume the app doesn't use something like `User.last.id` to count the number of users (since gaps would inflate the id, and lead to an inaccurate measure
- Assume sensible rails conventions are followed throughout
- I suspect choice of database won't matter, but in case it does, I'm using postgresql

## Example

Here's a small example of my thinking: say for a `has_one` association, I feel like the n’th x should match the n’th y. For example, if supplier `has_one` account, then the supplier with id: 29478 should match the account with id 29478. Or is this just wishful thinking and totally unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR nope - it doesn't matter one bit.

**Does it matter if the primary key (id) has 'gaps'?**

> Nope, let the db do its thing with primary keys. And don't rely on the id of the last record to be a count for how many records you have

**What about a has_one association e.g. where a supplier `has_one` account, then shouldn't the 29478th supplier match the 29478th account?**

> Wishful thinking and totally unnecessary to worry about.  As soon as you delete an account but not a supplier, your ids will no longer match.

> Think about it like this, if they were UUIDs, you’d never bat an eye about them being the same.